# External Redshift connection only works upon full access instead of ip restricted

Tags: amazon-redshift, connection-timeout, inbound-security-rule

I want to connect externally to my Redshift cluster (VPC, NOT classic) using aginity workbench. Hence I added my public ip address to the ec2 inbound rules, but I get a connection timeout.

When I allow all traffic to the inbound rules (0.0.0.0/0) it is possible to connect.Off course this is not a preferred solution because of security.

Does anybody have an idea why/where it is failing with my public ip (grabbed from whatismyipaddress.com)?